How to add customisable ng-content in a Storybook story in Angular
I've got a component for a badge where the text displayed in the badge is done with ng-content. I trying to create a Storybook story for this where I want the text in the badge to be customisable when viewing the story.
I've tried following the example mentioned here, but I might be doing something wrong. I moved from Storybook v6 to v8 and can't figure it out.
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, StoryObj } from "@storybook/angular";
import { BadgeDirective } from "./badge.directive";
import { ComponentsModule } from "../components.module";
import { ComponentServicesModule } from "../../services/component-services.module";

const meta: Meta<BadgeDirective> = {
  title: 'Components/Display content/Badge',
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata( {
      imports: [ ComponentsModule, ComponentServicesModule.forRoot() ]
    } )
  ]
};
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<BadgeDirective>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  name: 'Badge',
  args: {
    colorStyle: 'primary',
    content: 'My badge value'
  },
  render: ( args ) => ( {
    props: args,
    template: `<badge [badgeStyle]="colorStyle">${args.content}</badge>`
  } )
}

It's throwing an error saying content is not a known property of args. This is because content is not an actual Input() on the component like colorStyle is.
How can I make what is displayed in the badge in the template customisable for the user, so that when viewing storybook, they can adjust the text?

This is just a types issue, because of how the types were updated to try and be more accurate to what should be in args. This is a common scenario though and the following is how I typically handle it and recommend to others.
// I define an interface for anything I want to be in `args` that isn't an input/output, which maintains types and gives a place to document what the other args are, for anyone modifying these stories.
interface ExtraArgs {
  content: string
}

type StoryComponentType = BadgeDirective & ExtraArgs

const meta: Meta<StoryComponentType> = {
  ...,
};
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<StoryComponentType>;


Another note, unrelated to your actual question:
Unless you have a specific reason for manually inserting your arg into the template string, instead of letting Angular insert it from the template context, I would change the render function to the following:
render: ( args ) => ( {
  props: args,
  template: `<badge [badgeStyle]="colorStyle">{{content}}</badge>`
} )

The reason is because Storybook will fully rerender the story, if the template string changes. If you let Angular update it, in the template, then it will act like updating a property in a component and only rerender what is necessary based on the Angular app's change detection. For simple components this isn't a noticeable difference, but in a large component with a complex component constructor/ngOnInit, :enter animations, etc, you would see them rerun every time you change any value in Storybook's Controls.

i have the same problem and i already tried the solution proposed by MarkB. its the same solution stated in this blog article: https://tsvetan.dev/blog/article/render-angular-components-with-ng-content-in-storybook/
but its still throwing the error.
